# Math escape in listings and surround white space

Tags: math-mode, listings, unicode

I want to use the double right arrow for some Scala code in listings. I thought I'd use the mathescape option and `$\Rightarrow$`. However, this "eats" whitespace around it, e.g. if I have

```
foo  $\Rightarrow$  bar
```

only one space character is used in front and after the arrow, as if it were

```
foo $\Rightarrow$ bar
```

How do I enforce the whitespace? Could I embed the unicode character `\u21D2` for the arrow instead of using mathescape?

---

**EDIT**: So with the comments I managed to produce a math escaped command that has a width of exactly three space characters in the verbatim font:

```
\newcommand{\ScalaRA}{{}\hspace{-0.04ex}\Rightarrow\hspace{-0.08ex}{}}
```

*However*, the problem of eating the white space is still there:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
abc d     g     j
a   d  $\ScalaRA$g  $\ScalaRA$j
a   def$\ScalaRA$ghi$\ScalaRA$j
\end{lstlisting}
```

In the second line, after using `$\ScalaRA$` for the first time, *subsequent* whitespace is contracted: After the `g` character there are two spaces but it is rendered only as one space:

[image]

So going in an out of the math mode leaves some "garbage" behind somehow. How to clean this up so that all three lines are perfectly aligned and the two space characters after `g` in the second line are respected?

Comment: inserting "empty groups" around the symbol within the scope of math should insert the "usual" relation space: `${}\Rightarrow{}$`

Comment: Use `\newcommand{\ScalaRA}{\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ }` and then `foo$\ScalaRA$bar`. You could even use `\quad` instead of two manual spaces.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with both of these ideas is that the extra spaces are measured in terms of the maths font and not the tt font. Ideally I would like to have the whole construction a multiple of the tt space width, so that vertical columns still align. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the most convenient way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  literate={⇒}{\ScalaRA}{1}
}
\newcommand{\ScalaRA}{\mbox{$\Rightarrow$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
abc d     g     j
a   d   ⇒ g   ⇒ j
a   def ⇒ ghi ⇒ j
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @barbara-beeton and @werner 's comments, I came up with this:

```
\newcommand{\ScalaRA}{{}\hspace{-0.04ex}\Rightarrow\hspace{-0.08ex}{}}
```

The exact hspacing will depend on the tt font size. The only caveat is that in each line after the first usage of the math escape, to get multiple spaces one has to put an empty escape `$$` inbetween each two. Like so:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
abc d     g     j
a   d  $\ScalaRA$g $$ $\ScalaRA$j
a   def$\ScalaRA$ghi$\ScalaRA$j
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Slightly annoying, so if there are better answers, please add them.